# Is there a stop word list for twitter?

Tags: twitter, nlp, data-mining

I want to do some mining on tweets. Is there any more specific stop word list for tweets such as removing "lol" and other twitter smiley?

Answer (score 5):

I guess you should merge ordinary stop word list, like [this one](http://www.webconfs.com/stop-words.php) or [that](https://code.google.com/p/twitter-sentiment-analysis/source/browse/trunk/files/stopwords.txt?r=51), with the specific acronyms dictionary, e.g. [this slang dictionary](http://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/Twitter_Dictionary_Guide.asp), or [that](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/thesaurus/words+meaning+acronyms+%28list+of%29.html), or [that](http://www.internetslang.com/list.asp?i=A), or [that](http://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/textmessageabbreviations.asp) (the last one seems to be the easiest for parsing, see comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28770260/4588780) for the idea).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a specific stopwords list, but you could get a list of most frequent single words here:
http://clic.cimec.unitn.it/amac/twitter_ngram/ (download en.1grams.gz)

To detect and then ignore smilies use: https://github.com/brendano/tweetmotif

You may also find these tools useful:
https://github.com/willf/segment (if you want to segment hashtags)
https://github.com/amacinho/Rovereto-Twitter-Tokenizer (if you don't)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a Twitter-specific stop word list, but it is common practice to simply remove the n most frequent words from your analyses, where n could be 100, for example. Depending on what you would like to do, smileys may actually provide very relevant information.

Comment: I am doing some retrieval on tweets data. I think smileys are meaningless for my retrieval job.