# Is there a way to identify and create a list of all misspelled words in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column that has many misspelled words in it.

I would like to simply (a) identify all misspelled words in each cell on the next column and (b) produce a list of all unique misspelled words found (not duplicates).

For example I have,

```
Column 1
I worked fertl for a long time.
I worked at fhe desk job.
I am seeing a prw of it. 
cia and nba are both cool places to work
```

Desired output:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| I worked fertl for a long time. | fertl |
| I worked at fhe desk job. | fhe |
| I am seeing a prw of it. | prw |
| cia and nba are both cool places to work | cia, nba |

and also i want to get a list of all of these like:

{fertl, fhe, prw, cia, nba}

Comment: I don't. think this has much to do with Pandas. You might want to use a spell checker as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928155/spell-checker-for-python, but that is something else.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list of words. For example [english-words](https://pypi.org/project/english-words/)

```
from english_words import english_words_lowet_set as words

df['Column 2'] = [','.join({w for w in x.lower().split()
                            if w not in words})
                  for x in df['Column 1']]
```

Or, using sets:

```
df['Column 2'] = [','.join(set(x.lower().split())-words)
                  for x in df['Column 1']]
```

Comment: If `words` is a set, then you can actually just use `words.intersection(sentence.split())`. No need for a comprehension (unless the order of misspelled words is somehow important).

Comment: @ddejohn yes that's right. I however don't know this library, I just provided it as example so I went for the safe way ;)

Comment: @ddejohn in this case I think you meant `difference` (`set(sentence.split()).difference(words)`)

Comment: Ah, yes, correct. In that case though, you'd need `set(sentence.split()) - words`. And yes, `english_words_set` is a `set` :D